# Empty Strings While Entering Data into MySQL table using PHP foreach() Loop

Tags: php, mysql

Form

```
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="b[]">
<input type="text" name="c[]">
```

process_form.php

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$id = 12;
$query = "INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) VALUES ";
foreach($a as $i => $n) {
    $b = $_POST['b'][$i];
    $c = $_POST['c'][$i];
    $query = $query."('$id','$n', '$b', '$c') ,";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);
echo $query;
```

Output

```
INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) VALUES('12','a','b','c') , ('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','') ,('12','','','')
```

Required Output

```
INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) VALUES('12','a','b','c')
```

I don't why $i iterates 10 times and I am getting empty strings.

Comment: Why are you using `name="a[]"` for a text field? Do you have other elements in the form that have the same name?

Comment: You need to provide us with more info. Give us an example of the input data you're expecting to process. Without it we can't tell what you're trying to accomplish. You may not even need a foreach loop.

Comment: @Moe yes I have 10 name=a[] .

Comment: That's your problem. Everytime there is a `a[]` is on the page, the loop will run again. You should check to see if `a[]` has a value before adding to the `$query` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
  <?php
$a = array('a','aa','aaa');//assumed arrays
$b = array('b','bb','bbb');
$c = array('c','cc','ccc');
$query = "INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) ";
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if($key == (count($a)-1)){
        $query.=" VALUES(12,'$a[$key]','$b[$key]','$c[$key]')";
    }
       else{
    $query.="VALUES(12,'$a[$key]','$b[$key]','$c[$key]') ,";
       }
}
echo $query;

?>
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) VALUES(12,'a','b','c') ,VALUES(12,'aa','bb','cc') , VALUES(12,'aaa','bbb','ccc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// $a = $_POST['a'];
$id = 12;
$query = "INSERT INTO table(id,a,b,c) ";
$insert=array();

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST['a']);$i++) {
    $a = $_POST['a'][$i];
    $b = $_POST['b'][$i];
    $c = $_POST['c'][$i];
    //$query = $query."('$id','$n', '$b', '$c') ,";
    $insert[]="VALUES ('$id','$n', '$b', '$c')";
}
$query=$query.implode(',',$insert);
//$query = substr($query, 0, -1);
echo $query;
```